# How to add nic driver to iso through cubic

Tags: server

Has anyone added a network card driver to iso through cubic?

I compile the Intel i40e network card driver in cubic, and it prompts that the kernel header file is missing.
I tried to use apt install kernel-header. But it failed.

Does anyone know how to deal with it?

nic driver version:i40e-2.14.13
iso version: Ubuntu-20.04.01

[make install driver error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b0LHu.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the kernel files for the kernel shown at the top right on Cubic's Terminal page.

For example, if it shows "kernel 5.8.0-44-generic", execute...

```
apt update
apt install --reinstall linux-headers-5.8.0-44-generic linux-image-5.8.0-44-generic
```